# How to hide bottom bar on modal screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an app with a bottom bar and I'd like to present a modal screen from one of them **without** the bottom tab. I don't understand why it works as expected on iOS but not on Android.

Here is my bottom tab navigator which contains all my tabs:

```js
// AppStack.tsx

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

const AppStack = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="homeStack" >
      <Tab.Screen name="homeStack" component={HomeStack} />
      ...
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

And here is the stack navigator that contains several screens but also contains one screen that should be presented modally (thus without the bottom bar).

```js
// HomeStack.tsx

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="home">
      <Stack.Screen name="home" component={HomeScreen} />
      ...

      <Stack.Screen
        name="addStuff"
        component={StuffStack}
        options={{
          presentation: 'fullScreenModal',
        }}
      />

    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Presenting the `addStuff` modal screen from one of `HomeStack`'s screens works on iOS as expected: the bottom bar isn't displayed. But on Android, the bottom bar is still present...

```js
// HomeScreen.tsx
navigation.navigate('addStuff')
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to tell react-navigation not to add this bottom bar on this modal screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create conditional rules to check the screen name.

To achieve this, you need to get the navigation props (which is present on your `HomeStack`) and use the `getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute` method to get the current screen name:

```js
import {getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';
// rest of the codes ...

const HomeStack = ({route, navigation}) => {

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
    if (routeName === 'addStuff') {
      navigation.setOptions({tabBarVisible: false});
    } else {
      navigation.setOptions({tabBarVisible: true});
    }
  }, [navigation, route]);

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="home">
      <Stack.Screen name="home" component={HomeScreen} />
      // rest of the codes ...
      <Stack.Screen
        name="addStuff"
        component={StuffStack}
        options={{
          presentation: 'fullScreenModal',
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this seems to work as expected! I didn't know I could access navigation props from this place. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This was what worked for me.

Since modal screen is a Screen, it will be the same as we don't want to show bottom bar in a screen. so we just hide it from _layout.tsx file.

_layout.tsx

```
  <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: {
          display:
            usePathname() === '/path/to/modalScreen' ? 'none' : 'flex',
        },
      }}
      initialRouteName="home"
    >...
    /Tabs>
```